# Can I use file descriptors to create a custom filesystem?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, linux-device-driver

In a course I am enrolled in, I was tasked to create a filesystem with some custom features. I simply created an image of zeroes using dd, and created my filesystem by creating superblock, inodes, stat files, etc. for it. It can read/write files, import and export files and directories, with proper directory hierarchy.
Now I want to make this work with an actual physical partition. I looked at many places, and saw that file descriptors can be read as plain files. But I want to know if it relies on existing filesystem in the partition. Can I bypass everything and simply get a block-wise read/write interface, and with ability to seek to bytes or blocks? What would be the overhead on that?
Also, I want to turn it into a linux module so that my filesystem can work with file managers. What is the standard API interface that I need to implement to make it happen?

Please guide me to the right direction.

Comment: **Too many questions** in the single question post. Stack Overflow is a bad place for "where to start" sort of questions. If you want to implement toy filesystem in the Linux kernel, you may google for "linux kernel filesystem example", and follow one of that example.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options; integration into the kernel is relatively hard, whereas integrating with a user space file system framework (libfuse on github) is a good intermediate step.   At the end, you will have a usable file system.

Comment: I appreciate your recommending FUSE, but I really want to learn the straight way of actually implementing it in full. I'm still a student. I hope you understand.